# SQL Query to place prefix in all records of particular field

Tags: sql, mass-assignment

Second table was misconstructed using an integer instead of a string. Original table used a string. ( field's string is an amalgam of three other numeric IDs compacted into one field )

Turns out that linking to the other table with int-to-string has issues. I want to change the field in 2nd table from integer to a string and prefix "00" ( zero-zero ) in front of the existing integer - which is now a string. That's the only difference between the two.

I can probably match the two with a "LIKE" I guess, but want exact matches, and this should be a one-time fix.

Thanks!

Jolly

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What about (in MySQL)

```
SELECT CONCAT('00', CAST(field AS CHAR)) AS newfield
```

However, what about converting the first table from string to int?

Answer (score 0):

First add another columns of string data type with same data as integer data column.

**UPDATE table SET column2 = CAST(column1 AS CHAR)**

Then you can prefix '00' to the column to using following query.

UPDATE table SET column2 = CONCAT('00',column2)

HOpe this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySql you want to first change your datatype of the column, like this

```
ALTER TABLE tab MODIFY COLUMN IDBoth VARCHAR(10); -- or what ever size is needed
```

Then do an update with a concat like this:

```
UPDATE TAB as t1
JOIN tab as t2
ON t1.id1 = t2.id2 -- Add additionation join criteria if needed to get right join
SET t1.IDBOTH = CONCAT('00', t1.IDBOTH);
```

See it in action with this [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d5f4/1)